# How to show $f(x),g(x)$ are increasing or decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis

> If $f(x)=\frac{x}{\sin x},g(x)=\frac{x}{\tan x}, 0< x \leq 1$, then in this interval **(1)** both $f(x), g(x)$ are increasing functions **(2)** both $f(x), g(x)$ are decreasing functions **(3)** $f(x)$ is increasing function **(4)** $g(x)$ is increasing function.

Trial: $f'(x)=\frac{\sin x - x\cos x}{\sin^2x}$ and $g'(x)=\frac{\tan x -x\sec^2x}{\tan^2x}=\frac{\sin x\cos x-x}{\sin^2x}$

From here I can't conclude anything.please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Remember you are working in $(0,1)$.

Let $h(x)=\sin x-x\cos x$. Then $h(0)=0$ and $$h^{\prime}(x)=\cos x-\cos x+x\sin x=x\sin x> 0$$ in $(0,1)$. Can you continue?

Comment: Can I do this since $\sin^2x > 0$ in the given interval?

Comment: @Argha Because $(0,1)\subset (0,\pi)$ $\sin x> 0$ in $(0,1)$

Comment: This answer is clear to me. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Argha You mean without calculus?

Comment: yes you are right